# Extract EPOCH from DateTime of varchar type in Oracle

Tags: oracle

Postgres query:

```
SELECT extract(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP '2022-05-08T16:49:34Z') from table_name;
```

I need to convert the above Postgres query to an Oracle query.

I am new to Oracle and what I could come up with is,

```
SELECT (TO_TIMESTAMP('2022-05-08T16:49:34Z', 'yyyy-MM-dd"T"HH:mm:ssXXX')*24*3600) FROM DUAL;
```

but I am getting error,

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got TIMESTAMP
```

In Oracle, is there any reliable method to extract the EPOCH from the given DateTime(varchar)?

Comment: Will your timestamps ever include fractional seconds, and if so, do you need them preserved in the result?

Comment: To whoever closed this question: **Brilliant!** Do you understand that extracting epoch from a timestamp is not necessarily the same as extracting epoch from a date? In Oracle a timestamp may have fractional seconds, and if those must be preserved, there is absolutely nothing in an answer regarding "dates to epoch" that will help with this additional complication. "Community" (whoever that is) should consider reopening this question - or link to a relevant thread, if there is one.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.  I totally understand what you are saying. Regarding fractional seconds, actually, there is no reason to exclude that. Can you guide me on how I do that? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below as mentioned at : https://www.epochconverter.com/

```
Oracle PL/SQL:   
SELECT (CAST(SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(SYSTIMESTAMP) AS DATE) -
TO_DATE('01/01/1970','DD/MM/YYYY')) * 24 * 60 * 60 FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(trunc(TO_TIMESTAMP('2022-05-08T16:49:34Z', 'yyyy-MM-dd"T"HH:mm:ssXXX')) - TO_DATE('01/01/1970', 'MM/DD/YYYY')) * 24 * 60 * 60
```

Comment: ORA-01810: format code appears twice. I am getting this error.

Comment: select (trunc(TO_TIMESTAMP('2022-05-08T16:49:34Z', 'yyyy-MM-dd"T"HH:mm:ssXXX')) - TO_DATE('01/01/1970', 'MM/DD/YYYY')) * 24 * 60 * 60 from dual;